# Dynamic Matrix Problems with Free Matrix

Tags: c

I'm trying to read matrix dimension (`dim`) from user input and create `n*n` matrix dynamically.
But when I print the matrix my program crashes.

I searched in Stackoverflow, it could be a `free()` error.
I don't know why, but the program works when `dim < 5`.

```
        #include <stdio.h>
        #include <stdlib.h>

        typedef struct{
            float real, img;
        }COMPLEXO;

        void zeroIt(COMPLEXO **matrix, int dim){
            int i,j;
            for(i=0;i<dim;i++){
                for(j=0;j<dim;j++){
                    matrix[i][j].real=0;
                    matrix[i][j].img=0;
                }
            }
        }

        int main(void){
            int dim, i, j;
            COMPLEXO **matrix;
            int flag = 1;
            /*Pedir Dimensao da Matrix*/
            printf("DIM: \n");
            scanf("%d", &dim);
            /*Alocar espaço*/
            matrix = (COMPLEXO **) malloc(sizeof(dim) * sizeof(COMPLEXO));
            /*Alocar linhas*/
            for(i = 0; i < dim; i++){
                matrix[i] = (COMPLEXO *) malloc(sizeof(dim) * sizeof(COMPLEXO));
            }
            if(matrix == NULL){
                printf("Erro");
                return;
            }

            /* Escrever dados */

            for(i=0;i<dim;i++){
                for(j=0;j<dim;j++){
                    matrix[i][j].real = i;
                    matrix[i][j].img = j;
                }
            }
            printf("#insert matrix - done\n\n");

            /* Imprimir dados */
            for(i=0;i<dim;i++){
                for(j=0;j<dim;j++){
                    printf("%.f|%.f ", matrix[i][j].real, matrix[i][j].img);
                }
                printf("\n");
            }

            printf("#print matrix - done \n\n");
            zeroIt(matrix, dim);
            for(i=0;i<dim;i++){
                free(matrix[i]);
            }
            free(matrix);
            printf("#free pointer - done \n\n");
            getchar();
            return 0;
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy guys,

```
matrix = (COMPLEXO **) malloc(dim * sizeof(COMPLEXO*));
```

Answer (score 2):

Your first malloc should use `sizeof(COMPLEXO*)`, not `sizeof(COMPLEXO)`.  You're allocating an array of pointers, not an array of structs.

Comment: Yes, now that I think about it, your structure should be at least the size of a pointer, so it shouldn't matter.  Where exactly does the program die?

Answer (score 0):

You should move the NULL check to be right after malloc call, so you can catch the problem before you use the pointer... (this is not the case of your error, you would have to have full RAM and swap to experience this):

```
        matrix = (COMPLEXO **) malloc(sizeof(dim) * sizeof(COMPLEXO));

        if(matrix == NULL){
            printf("Error");
            return;
        }
```

Next to make the checking for allocation errors complete, you should add check inside your for loop:

```
        for(i = 0; i < dim; i++){
            matrix[i] = (COMPLEXO *) malloc(sizeof(dim) * sizeof(COMPLEXO));
            if(matrix[i]==NULL)
            {
                printf("Not enough memory");
                return ;
            }
        }
```

You could then test it using some grotesquely large number of DIM like `2000000000`.